# Swift: How to remove green border from picker in watchos? Any Picker Styling?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

There is a green border across picker and I am not sure on how can i remove this. Can somebody please help me out with this?

If possible can someone please also recommend me on how can I style this picker to have a background or something fancy.

[image]

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444466/3151675

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question, so that it's only about one thing at a time (in this case, since the picker border part of the question is a duplicate, leaving only the picker styling part)