# Change the color of a focused element (Picker) SwiftUI - WatchOS

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swiftui, uipickerview

How can I change the focus color of a selected element in WatchOS7 with swiftUI. Here's my example below with a Picker whose focus color is green (the default one) but I want to change it to blue to be consistant with my app layout.

[image]

I search over the internet and stackoverflow but did not find andy solution to this. Is it possible to do it in SwiftUI.

Comment: Ditto. With UIKit could use https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect I would assume, but seem stuck in watchOS.

Comment: its changing the TableView colour while I have used SwiftUI Picker View

Comment: Qazi, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Daniel No I did't find the solution till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the focus color and you cannot change it. At least no with standard view modifiers like `.accentColor`, `.tint`, etc.

You can try to hide it by overlying another view (like in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444466/4473187)), for example, or try to reach to UIKit using instrospection.

Probably it's best to be at peace with the fact that it's system behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind building your own picker-type view, you can use `.digitalCrownRotation()` instead of the picker as discussed here in regards to hiding the border: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75909943/21505031

Example code here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-read-the-digital-crown-on-watchos-using-digitalcrownrotation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34150666)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try using `.accentColor` modifier to the picker.